# MULE 4 : Stored Procedures : How to pass SET statement while executing a MSSQL server STORED PROCEDURE in MULE 4?

Tags: database, stored-procedures, mule4, mule-connector

MSSQL server provides set statements that can be passed while executing stored procedures.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-quoted-identifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

As per the requirement need to pass `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON` in the stored procedure call from Database connector.
From the Mule documentation https://docs.mulesoft.com/db-connector/1.13/database-stored-procedure Could not find any information.

Can someone please guide me here ?

Stored Procedure call in DB looks like this :

```
USE [sampleDatabase]
GO
set quoted_identifier OFF
DECLARE    @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[test_studentRecords]
        @studentMarks="[]",
        @studentRollNumber= '2345678',
SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you need to **PASS** the statement SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON. You mean like an input parameter?

Comment: In the attached query, we are using " set quoted_identifier OFF "  How can we specify this in the Mule DB connector for Stored procedure @HarshankBansal